# Error filtering template: Invalid Document Element 'widget': Missing child element(s). Expected is one of ( label, description, containers ). Line: 4

Tags: magento2

I am facing this issue at home page after click on reorder in my order at frontend.

Answer (score 1):

The issue: One of your `widget.xml` files missing required child element(s), which causes this error:

> Invalid Document Element 'widget': Missing child element(s). Expected is one of ( label, description, containers ). Line: 4

The widget requires `label` and `description` elements. You can read more from Magento official document https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/tutorials/frontend/create-custom-widget/

Solution:
You can detect which file has a problem by adding debug code in `vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php`, inside `validate` method, after the following code:

```
if ($this->validationState->isValidationRequired()) {
    $errors = $this->validateDomDocument($this->dom, $schemaFileName, $this->errorFormat);
```

Add this code:

```
if (count($errors)) {
    var_dump($this->dom->textContent);
    die();
}
```

Clear cache and go to the page which has the error, you will see the text content of the widget file which has the problem. Copy some text to find in the whole project, and you will see the `widget.xml` file which causes the error.

Open the error file, go to line `4` (that line mentioned in the error message above), which is the widget that caused the error, and add `label` and `description` elements to that widget to resolve the issue.

Clear cache and see the result.

Once you resolve all errors, remove the debugging code in `vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php`.